# How to deploy two separate repositories on the same domain with Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have two nextjs repositories for landing page and blog, `Repository A` & `Repository B` deployed on Vercel.

I already deployed Repository A with domain `mypage.com`, and I want to attach my Repository B as `mypage.com/blog`.

I would like to know the step how I can manage these architecture on Vercel & nextjs projects.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for something similar to what's called "Multi Zones", as repository B is probably a separate app.

For Vercel hosting, you will probably need to create a **monorepo**.

I have found an article in the Next.js documentation and you might want to follow the instructions from there. Article [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones).